# How can I make an ellipse above a letter in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, accents

In Jancewicz's 1980 paper *Electromagnetism using Bivectors*, he introduces a new notation for bivectors: a letter with an ellipse above it, by analogy to the traditional arrow for straight vectors.

The arrow for a straight vector is easy enough: `\vec{x}`. If I prefer boldface for vectors, that's easy enough too (just redefine `\vec` as `\mathbf`).

But there doesn't seem to be any sort of builtin for an "ellipse above" diacritic. How can I create such a thing?

This is my goal: [image: example from Jancewicz]

Extremely boring MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ \vec{B} = \mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This diacritic doesn't seem to be in Unicode; at least I can't find it in the current charts.  Can you provide a more precise reference, with page number, preferably online?  (I will be happy to submit it to the Unicode committee for consideration.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm not sure it's used outside Jancewicz, but I'd certainly be glad to see it in Unicode! See page 181 [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/1/3/013/pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The `accents` package allows one to define accents.  The syntax to define a new accent is
`\accentset{〈accent〉}{〈symbol〉}`.

There is no ellipse in the standard math alphabet.  You can get one by horizontally stretching a circle: `\hstretch{2}{\circ}`.  Parameter `2` can be modified; it defines the scale factor.  `hstretch` command is provided by the `scalerel` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[single]{accents}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand*{\ellipse}{\hstretch{2}{\circ}}
\renewcommand*{\vec}[1]{\accentset{\ellipse}{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\vec{B} = a \wedge b$

\end{document}
```

Comment: My sincere compliments. I was working also on this question :-).